# Is it possible to use Eclipse IDE as just a text editor?

Tags: eclipse, text-editor

Is it possible to use Eclipse IDE just as a text editor (with features like sytax highlighting, etc., possibly with extra features) , by dragging files into it or using a 'File>Open' kind of thing, without creating any "Projects" and the like, editing the files and saving them to their original location? Is this a feature built into Eclipse, or would a plugin be necessary?

(In case the language makes a difference, this is for Python, although information for other languages would also be useful.)

Comment: Notepad++ is a great text editor for multiple languages if you don't have to use Eclipse.

Comment: Even if it is possible, why not use something more lightweight? Imo Eclipse is much too heavy for just be used as a text editor.

Comment: Lightweight--hmm, I keep eclipse loaded all day, it's always responsive and can do some great stuff with nearly any type of file.  There is no advantage of light weight except for startup and memory size, neither of which should be a problem for most developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Eclipse SDK

Version: 3.5.0
Build id: I20090611-1540

And yes, you can open a .txt file, make changes, then save and it will save the file to the original open location.

Just did it.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you *can*, but it has much the same feeling as chartering a 747 to taxi to the convenience store.

Comment: I.e. It'll take a long time, but it'll be *comfy*. Especially if you book Executive Class.

Comment: Not in all circumstances. E.g. opening an XML file in Eclipse will give you a nice GUI-based editor.

Comment: Well, you could remove all plugins that are not needed, and you have a very slim eclipse RCP with a text editor plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Python syntax highlighting, but yes, it's completely possible to use it as a text editor. I've even prettified single files of C++ code in Eclipse; just drag-'n-drop the file into the window.

Answer (score 0):

I use Eclipse for:

- text editor
- Sql perspective (sql client)
- Task list
- Find in files (Open Resource by name)
- Svn plugin (subversion client)

and many other useful task.

I would like to make it more light by removing the Java compiler and SDK.
How can I do that?

Comment: You mustn't answer the question and ask the new one at the same time!